# Numbering Two Elements in a Vector in R

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
[1] "Food" "Drink"    "Food" "Drink"    "Drink"    "Food" "Food" "Food" "Food"
[10] "Food" "Food" "Drink"    "Food" "Drink"    "Food" "Food" "Food" "Food"
[19] "Drink"    "Food" "Food" "Food" "Drink"    "Food" "Food" "Food" "Food"
[28] "Food" "Food" "Drink"    "Drink"    "Food" "Food" "Food" "Drink"    "Food"
```

I want to number the elements, but separarely. So the numbering would be:

Food1, Drink1, Food2, Drink2, Drink3

I was able to do this VERY ineffectively with a for-loop:

```
# c <- c()
# Drink.counter = 1
# Food.counter = 1
# for (i in 1:length(groups.df)){ 
#   if(groups.df[i] == "Drink") { 
#      c <- c(c,paste0("Drink",Drink.counter))
#      Drink.counter <- Drink.counter + 1
#   } else { 
#     c <- c(c, paste0("Food",Food.counter))
#     Food.counter <- Food.counter + 1
#   }
#   }
```

Any effective ways?

Comment: Try `paste0(x, data.table::rowid(x))`

Comment: FANTASTIC!  I love data.table, and this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: `make.unique(x, '')` if you can stand `Food, Food1, Food2, ...` or `tail(make.unique(c(unique(x), x), ''), -length(unique(x)))` if you can't